# ¿Como hacer una función que se ejecute automáticamente en JavaScript sin la necesidad de que alguien se conecte a la pagina web?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una función donde verifico si el día actual pertenece al rango de fecha existente si no pertenece se calculara el nuevo rango de fecha y se insertara a la tabla.

La función funciona pero solo cuando el usuario entra a la pagina pero yo quiero que esa función se ejecute automáticamente sin la necesidad de que alguien ingrese a la pagina.

¿Alguien sabe si se puede lograr esto y que debo modificar?

También estaba pensando si mejor es hacer esto pero en la misma BD

**¿Es posible hacer esto en trigger en la BD?**

```js
function verificar_rango_fecha(){
  var FechaApertura = $("#FechaApertura").val();//2018-10-23    
  var FechaCierre = $("#FechaCierre").val();//2018-10-29  
  var f = new Date();//2018-10-30
  var dia=f.getDate();
  var mes=f.getMonth() +1;
  var anio=f.getFullYear();
  var FechaActual = anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia; 
  
  //N_fecha_apertura(FechaCierre) me traeria : 2018-10-30 
  
  //N_fecha_cierre(FechaActual) me traeria : 2018-11-05

  //Se compararia si 2018-10-30(FechaActual) = 2018-10-30 se inserta un   nuevo intervalo    de fechas
  
  if (FechaActual == N_fecha_apertura(FechaCierre)){
      alert("Insertar rango fecha");
    var N_FechaCierre = N_fecha_cierre(FechaActual);
    actualizar_rango_fecha(FechaActual,N_FechaCierre);
  }else{
    alert("Mismo rango fecha");
  }
}


  function N_fecha_apertura(FechaCierre){
    //OBTENER LA NUEVA FECHA APERTURA
    var fecha = new Date(FechaCierre);
    var dias = 1; 
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);

    var salida = formato(fecha.toISOString().substring(0, 10));

    var dia =salida.substring(0, 2);
    var mes =salida.substring(3, 5);
    var anio =salida.substring(6, 10);

    var FechaApertura = anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
    return FechaApertura;
  }
  
  function N_fecha_cierre(FechaApertura){
    //OBTENER LA NUEVA FECHA CIERRE
    var fecha = new Date(FechaApertura);
    var dias = 6; 
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);

    var salida = formato(fecha.toISOString().substring(0, 10));

    var dia =salida.substring(0, 2);
    var mes =salida.substring(3, 5);
    var anio =salida.substring(6, 10);

    var FechaCierre = anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
    return FechaCierre;

  }
```

Comment: Si el usuario no va a interactuar no veo lógico usar js, entonces investiga sobre cron jobs creo que ese es el nombre para que la bd lo haga en automático cada intervalo de tiempo

Comment: Fuera de tu sistema activo no será posible con el js que tienes. Debes de generar un job diario en tu base de datos o crear algún servicio en tu servidor para que realice la tarea que buscas.

Comment: La respuesta es no, no se puede ejecutar tu script sin que entren a tu pagina, ni con el trigger ya que no es su función... la mejor manera de desencadenar eventos por rangos de fecha es utilizar "store procedure" en tu base de datos.

Comment: Tenemos muy poca información sobre el stack tecnológico que usas, por ejemplo, ¿qué base de datos usas? ¿qué tecnología usas en backend? Además parece que tienes un fallo conceptual. Ese código parece interactuar con el DOM de tu HTML. ¿Como se invoca esta función? Parece que al final lo que hace es mostrar un alert y llamar a otra función. No sabemos que hace tu otra función. ¿Cuál es tu intención final para querer ejecutar ese código en servidor? Hasta donde nosotros sabemos, solo muestra un alert, que evidentemente no puedes mostrar en servidor. ¿Cambia la siguiente función algo en BD?